# Cassandra data modeling - Do I choose hotspots to make the query easier?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

**Is it ever okay to build a data model that makes the fetch query easier even though it will likely created hotspots within the cluster?**

While reading, please keep in mind I am not working with Solr right now and given the frequency this data will be accessed I didn’t think using spark-sql would be appropriate.  I would like to keep this as pure Cassandra.

We have transactions, which are modeled using a UUID as the partition key so that the data is evenly distributed around the cluster.  One of our access patterns requires that a UI get all records for a given user and date range, query like so:

```
select * from transactions_by_user_and_day where user_id = ? and created_date_time > ?;
```

The first model I built uses the user_id and created_date (day the transaction was created, always set to midnight) as the primary key:

```
CREATE transactions_by_user_and_day (
    user_ id int,
    created_date timestamp,
    created_date_time timestamp,
    transaction_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, created_date), created_date_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_date_time DESC);
```

This table seems to perform well.  Using the created_date as part of the PK allows users to be spread around the cluster more evenly to prevent hotspots.  However, from an access perspective it makes the data access layer do a bit more work that we would like.  It ends up having to create an IN statement with all days in the provided range instead of giving a date and greater than operator:

```
select * from transactions_by_user_and_day where user_id = ? and created_date in (?, ?, …) and created_date_time > ?;
```

To simplify the work to be done at the data access layer, I have considered modeling the data like so:

```
CREATE transactions_by_user_and_day (
    user_id int,
    created_date_time timestamp,
    transaction_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_global_id), created_date_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_date_time DESC);
```

With the above model, the data access layer can fetch the transaction_id’s for the user and filter on a specific date range within Cassandra.  However, this causes a chance of hotspots within the cluster.  Users with longevity and/or high volume will create quite a few more columns in the row.  We intend on supplying a TTL on the data so anything older than 60 days drops off.  Additionally, I’ve analyzed the size of the data and 60 days’ worth of data for our most high volume user is under 2 MB.  Doing the math, if we assume that all 40,000 users (this number wont grow significantly) are spread evenly over a 3 node cluster and 2 MB of data per user you end up with a max of just over 26 GB per node ((13333.33*2)/1024).  In reality, you aren’t going to end up with 1/3 of your users doing that much volume and you’d have to get really unlucky to have Cassandra, using V-Nodes, put all of those users on a single node.  From a resources perspective, I don’t think 26 GB is going to make or break anything either.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date Model 1:Something else you could do would be to change your data access layer to do a query for each ID individually, instead of using the IN clause. Check out this page to understand why that would be better.

https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

Data model 2: 26GB of data per node doesn't seem like much, but a 2MB fetch seems a bit large.  Of course if this is an outlier, then I don't see a problem with it.  You might try setting up a cassandra-stress job to test the model. As long as the majority of your partitions are smaller than 2MB, that should be fine.

One other solution would be to use Data Model 2 with Bucketing.  This would give you more overhead on writes as you'd have to maintain a bucket lookup table as well though.  Let me know if need me to elaborate more on this approach.

Comment: Thanks @gsteiner. I had not thought about the issues using an IN clause could present, thanks for pointing me in that direction. Having the data access layer perform that many queries is still something we'd like to shy away from, it just seems strange us (maybe that's the relational world we've lived in so long talking). I'll certainly do some stress testing with the data to see how that works out. I'd love to hear more about bucketing. I've read a bit about it and it seems like I'd still be running several queries at the data access layer, getting buckets that I need then querying them.

Comment: It is a very "relational" thing to not want to do a lot of queries.  Cassandra actually works better with lots of queries since each query will use a coordinator node that is best for that query.

Yup, with buckets you would still need to do multiple queries but it would be less queries than Model 1.  Just depends on your bucket size.